# Variables de clases utilizadas en funciones

Tags: python

He empezado un proyecto en Udemy de Python, más concretamente el Milestone Project 2, en este, se utilizan muchas clases y funciones, pero hay una cosa particularmente que me cuesta entender. ¿Por qué cuando define una variable dentro de una clase la llama desde una función? Sería algo así como se muestra en el ejemplo de abajo:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self): 
        self.value = 0

def example(some_variable):
    print(some_variable.value)
```

¿Cómo es esto posible?
Gracias y disculpad por la ignorancia, tal vez, he sido yo que no lo he entendido bien.

[Codigo completo aquí](https://pastebin.com/Y5YxgjTA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partiendo de tu ejemplo:

```
class Example:
  def __init__(self):
      self.value = 0
```

apuntar un detalle de nomenclatura. `value` en este caso no sería un atributo de clase, sino un atributo **de objeto**. Los atributos de clase son otra cosa (que es compartido solo para lectura entre todos los objetos de la misma clase, y que en python a penas se usan).

Lo que ocurre cuando creas un nuevo objeto de tipo `Example`, mediante una instrucción como la siguiente:

```
ej = Example()
```

es que Python en primer lugar crea un nuevo objeto "anónimo" de la clase `Example` (para lo cual llama a `Example.__new__()`, que normalmente no es necesario implementar salvo que quieras hacer cosas muy raras). Ese nuevo objeto recién creado, se asigna a la variable `ej`, y seguidamente se llama al constructor, es decir, a `Example.__init__(ej)`, es decir, se le pasa como parámetro ese objeto recién creado.

Dentro de esa función, el primer parámetro suele llamarse `self` por convenio, y ese parámetro recibe, como acabamos de ver, el objeto recién creado (en nuestro ejemplo, la variable `ej`). Por tanto cuando dentro del constructor haces `self.value=0`, en realidad estás haciendo `ej.value=0`, es decir, en ese momento estás *creando* un atributo llamado `value` en el objeto `ej`, y le estás dando el valor cero a ese atributo.

Una vez ha sido creado, puedes acceder a él desde cualquier otra parte del programa en la que `ej` sea visible, haciendo `ej.value`. Así puedes no sólo consultar su valor, sino también cambiarlo con cosas como `ej.value = 3`. Si vienes del C++ o de Java, te ayudará (y te sorprenderá!) saber que Python no tiene posibilidad de hacer un atributo *privado*. Es decir, es visible y manipulable "desde fuera".

Lo que estás viendo en el código que has enlazado es que se están creando objetos y después se están pasando como parámetros a otras funciones. Lógicamente, desde esas funciones una vez que recibes una referencia al objeto, puedes acceder a sus atributos. Por ejemplo:

```
def mostrar_value(objeto):
    print(objeto.value)
```

Para que esto funcione, el parámetro que le pases a esta función ha de ser un objeto que tenga el atributo `value`. Nuestra anterior variable `ej` cumple este requisito, por lo que puedes hacer:

```
mostrar_value(ej)
```

y la función mostrará `ej.value`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora lo entiendo bien, ya podré seguir con el proyecto correctamente. Saludos